# How can I reuse a text portion with commands in nroff?

Tags: groff, troff

When writing a UNIX manual page, I realized that some phrase occurs multiple times. I'd like to define it once and reuse it (not by copying with the editor). I see that I can use variables (`.ds`) for multi-line text, but it fails when the phrase includes dot commands (like `.B foo`). Is there a solution (other than include files and the C preprocessor) for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your multi-line text into a macro.  The downside is that to insert it you must invoke the macro rather than interpolating the string.

```
.de Us
The usage example is
.B very
important
..

Text text text
.Us
more text more text
```

If you just need bolding inside your strings, you can include font changes:

```
.ds Us You can use \fB bold \fR text in your strings \
and it will work fine

text text \*(Us
```

Comment: The solution looks simple, but doesn't seem to work: I don't get the `very` in output.

Comment: The second one works, but still this is not the solution for my question.

Comment: I tested this and it worked for me using either `man` or `gnroff -man` on a linux box.  What's your environment? It's possible that the version of man you have doesn't support defining macros like this, tho that seems unlikely.  Do you have a fuller example of what's not working for you?

Comment: I'm using openSUSE 42.2 with `groff-1.22.2-8.17.x86_64`. The text output is `Text text text The usage example is important more text more text`.